# Wrong emoji display

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chat, emoji

As you can see, I'm trying to display at the input the same emoji that I'm seeing at the emoji options, but when I click on them, they actually change the version and I just can see an old version (native) at the input. I'm using Google Chrome and when I open the same localhost at the mobile version, it shows what I want (apple emoji version). Could you help me? Thank you a lot! :)

[image: Not showing same version]

```
"emoji-mart": {
      "version": "3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/emoji-mart/-/emoji-mart-3.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-r5DXyzOLJttdwRYfJmPq/XL3W5tiAE/VsRnS0Hqyn27SqPA/GOYwVUSx50px/dXdJyDSnvmoPbuJ/zzhwSaU4A==",
      "requires": {
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.0.0",
        "prop-types": "^15.6.0"
      }
    }

import { Picker } from "emoji-mart";
import "emoji-mart/css/emoji-mart.css";
```

I already installed the dependencies from [emoji-mart-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emoji-mart):

```
npm install emoji-datasource-apple
npm install emoji-datasource-google
npm install emoji-datasource-twitter
npm install emoji-datasource-facebook
```

I bet it could have a problem between emoji-mart-native and [emoji-mart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emoji-mart), but I'm not sure

```
const addEmoji = (e: any) => {
    let emoji = e.native; 
    //e.apple here doesn't work. Downward I'm gonna show the difference between e.native and e.apple
    settextMessage(textMessage + emoji);
  };

<li>
  <ButtonDropdown
  className="emoji-dropdown"
  direction="up">
     <DropdownToggle
     id="emoji"
     color="link"
     className="text-decoration-none font-size-16 btn-lg waves-effect">
     <i className="ri-emotion-happy-line"></i>
     </DropdownToggle>
     <DropdownMenu className="dropdown-menu-lg-right">
           <Picker set="apple" onSelect={addEmoji} />
     </DropdownMenu>
  </ButtonDropdown>
  <UncontrolledTooltip target="emoji" placement="top">
      Emoji
  </UncontrolledTooltip>
</li>
```

'set' prop documentation:

[image: set documentation]

e.native (which upside I commented that it probably would receive e.apple but it doesn't show anything when I do):

[image: e.native]

e.apple (The emojis I would like to send, instead of an old version (native))

[image]

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm pretty sure emoji are encoded the same regardless of which version is displayed. How it's displayed is up to the system to determine, there isn't a separate unicode character for native/apple emojis.